# How to view SQL_TEXT in V$SQL that are COMMITed in Oracle Database?

Tags: oracle11g

I am trying to look the SQL query that has Updated, Inserted, and Deleted rows in a table

```
SELECT
* 
FROM V$SQL 
WHERE 
PARSING_SCHEMA_NAME = 'user_checking' and 
SQL_TEXT like '%employees%' 
order by FIRST_LOAD_TIME desc;
```

But this query also shows uncommitted queries. Is there a way to only show SQL_TEXT that has been commited?

Comment: To tell whether a particular command had been committed, you'd probably have to use Log Miner to work through the transaction logs, which would be highly inefficient and likely inaccurate. In general people usually use auditing of some kind to track the kind of modifications you're talking about, rather than SQL monitoring.